# Copy Row Data from one to another sheet base on Yes condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to copy data from one sheet to another sheet base on Yes condition in I column. I can add data in new sheet but in copy at same row again & again. I want if my 3rd row have fill, than they copy data at 5 than 6 row etc. This code only run when I select yes option from dropdown.

MS Excel 2013

File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfpjrmm1fgc6my3/EXCEL%20FORMULA.xlsm?dl=0

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Response
    Dim rng As Range, rngToDel As Range
    Dim fAddr As String

    If Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    MsgBox (lastrow)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MsgBox (lastrow)
        If UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then
            Response = vbYes
            If Response = vbYes Then

                .Range("A" & lastrow).Resize(, 50).Value = _
                Range("A" & Target.Row).Resize(, 50).Value
                MsgBox "Record added"
            End If
        End If
    End With


ExitHere:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

Issue that I am facing: lastrow only give me 2nd row of Sheet2 again & again and overwrite data with new rows.

Comment: Do you need to copy the data everytime is changed? This could be a 1 time refresh whenever you need and copy everything on the sheet. right?

Comment: Why do you use `ActiveSheet` inside a fully qualified `With` worksheet statement? Also: The missing `.` before `Range("A" & Target.Row).Resize(, 50).Value` might cause Problems.

Comment: On a sidenote: Your exact code is working for me; 50 colums are copied under existing data on `Sheet2`.

Comment: @Nacorid , Above code copy data perfectly. Issue is when I assign Yes option 4-5 rows in sheet1, In sheet2 all data overwrite with the last.

Comment: @Nacorid If I select 5 yes in sheet1, in sheet2 we must get 5 rows. But its only shown lats one. Above and below code only over write the records with new one.

Comment: Yes @Damian, I want to copy data every time when its change. If I open sheet and update 5 rows with Yes in sheet 1, at the same time these rows must be shown at sheet2. Data copy working fine but issue with creating rows in sheet2.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, it's working fine for me

Comment: @Nacorid check this video: https://streamable.com/tgjx8 I get this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim WsSource As Worksheet, WsDest As Worksheet

    Set WsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set WsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    If Intersect(Target, WsSource.Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Debug.Print LastRow
    With WsDest
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Debug.Print LastRow
        If UCase(Target.Text) = "YES" Then
            .Range("A" & LastRow).Resize(, 50).Value = _ 
                WsSource.Range("A" & Target.Row).Resize(, 50).Value
            Debug.Print "Record added"
        End If
    End With

ExitHere:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

Comment: Same issue, When I have updated multiple rows with yes, in Sheet2 I only get last one row. Its over write the data

Comment: Is there any data in column "A" on source sheet? It worked for me so probably sth wrong with Column "A" and data in it.

Comment: Coloumn A is empty, No data in it. I double checked when I have select Yes, only 2 row updated in sheet everytime.

Comment: `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` this checks for data on destination sheet in column "A". You have a header in row one so `.row` returns 1 and then +1 =2. So it will always paste in row 2. You need to change `"A"` to some other column that always holds some data and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to copy:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim LastRow As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then '<- If target change is in columnI

        LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 '<- Find last row of sheet 2 column A

        If UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then '<- If target value is "YES"

            Sheet1.Range("A" & Target.Row & ":O" & Target.Row).Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & LastRow) '<- Copy from sheet 1 range A:O target.row to sheet 2 last row

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```